# Filter/Sort whole sections in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, cell

I want to sort and filter whole cell sections in Excel.
For example I have two 3x3 arrays. I have named first array as "ccc" workbook. Second array I have named "aaa". Is there any solution that in one cell I will create filter or sorter that will hide whole array "ccc" or take array "aaa" and put it above array "ccc"?

5   6   b
a   g   1   <<< ccc
p   4   5

d   o   a
d   e   7   <<< aaa
s   f   6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to name your tables and to then place a filter on the data column of the table name.

[image]

[image]

You can then pull together any combination of tables that you like as so

[image]

Question is very brief so this was my interpretation of what you was after.

Comment: But if you want make my question more clear. I want to create something like movie database with pictures. First column would be pictures in 10 - 40 rows. Second column would be text next to every picture. Above that columns will be row with movie name. There will be about 1000 movies. So I wants to filter them and sort them by name of the movie.